# Internal DNS server ignored when using Edge and Android

Tags: internal-dns

I have a domain name publicly connected to my home address, so I can access a webserver locally. For example: webserver.domain.com

But when trying to reach this from inside my home, I get on the web page of my router.

So I tried setting up a DNS server internally to be able to define static addresses with their internal IP address. For example: webserver.domain.com -> 192.168.0.10

When trying to use nslookup to find the location, it responds fine. But when trying to reach the webserver by its URL, I still get to the web interface of my modem.

For Windows I already found two rootcauses:

Mark Wifi as private and not as public
Disabling "Use DNS over HTTPS" works, but I want to stay secure so I don't want to disable this
For Android I already found 1 thing:

Disabling "Use Private DNS" works, but also here I would like to stay secure.
I have used both Pi-Hole and AdGuard, but I can't get them to work stable with the options mentioned on (to stay secure).

Someone any idea how I could fix this? Because I would like to setup a DNS provider which is working for both Windows and Anroid browsers.

Comment: DNS is system agnostic, given the same DNS server, it should return no differently for any client. LLMNR *could* be at play, but I would have to see packet dumps to be certain... IP Cache could be at play as well, and the clients are remembering the public IP of your router from the last public DNS query, then looping back to it. Have you tried querying the DNS sever actually in use on the two clients directly, bypassing client lookups? (Change server in NSLOOKUP). What does ping return for the same URI?

Comment: One more thing to note, your router could be pointing 80/443 to an internal server via PAT on the WAN, and reserving it for admin interface on the LAN. Does your router have the ability to change its admin interface web server ports in configuration?

Comment: Sorry I'm not that familiar with the way DNS works underneath. Normally I'm a programmer, so I know the basics of DNS, but that's it. So I'm sorry if I don't understand it immediately.

Comment: I used "github.com/ameshkov/dnslookup" to check DNS on several levels, so plain-dns works, dns-over-tls works, dns-over-https works. But I'm not sure what Edge and Android are using exactly. I have cleared the DNS cache in edge underneath edge://net-internals but when trying to look it up there it still uses the public IP. I have checked Chrome and there it responded when calling "dns.domain.com" with my internal DNS server, but when doing the same from Edge it responded with the web page of my modem. I can't change the ports of my Genexis modem.